# SpringBoot application crash

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tell me please where I have problem?
I try to start my first application developed on Spring Boot.
I already have simple web project on SpringMVC and now I like to build it on BOOT.
Here is error output:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAO lv.intrade.example.services.Dictionary.translationDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAO lv.intrade.example.services.Dictionary.translationDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1711)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2014-12-30 23:21:01.568  INFO 3552 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-12-30 23:21:01.569 ERROR 3552 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:914)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:490)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at lv.intrade.example.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

2014-12-30 23:21:01.572 ERROR 3552 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAO lv.intrade.example.services.Dictionary.translationDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    ...
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at lv.intrade.example.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAO lv.intrade.example.services.Dictionary.translationDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'translationDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAOImpl.emf; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1a666bf: startup date [Tue Dec 30 23:20:58 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1711)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

`

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bootExample</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And here is my Application.class

```
@ComponentScan("lv.intrade.example")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I have more 3 classes with `@Configuration` and `@Order` annotations where I've placed `@Bean` definitions. 
If need more information, ask me! 
I can't find some worked example with needed features.

Comment: @MDeinum Hi! May be you can help me with new idea where i lost some?

Comment: Please add your additional configuration. One thing is that your `Application` class should have `@Configuration` also. Tip if it is already in the `lv.intrade.example` package the `@ComponentScan` can be empty and better all annotations can be replaced by a single `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: [Initializer.java](http://pastebin.com/mtZDrEMb)
[RootConfig.java](http://pastebin.com/WeCR1aNP)
[WebAppConfig.java](http://pastebin.com/uTDRch7p)

Comment: I tired disable all of my annotations and set the `@SpringBootApplication` but have the same error with caused first by this error: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public lv.intrade.example.dao.TranslationDAO lv.intrade.example.services.Dictionary.translationDAO;...`

Comment: Your `Initializer` can be dropped it doesn't do a thing in a Spring Boot application. Now I should mention that you should work with the framework and you seem to be working around it. (You should be able to basically remove almost all of your configuration and add some properties to an `application.properties` file). I guess that excluding the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` from being applied should fix this.

Comment: I remove last two `@Bean` definitions from `RootConfig.java` and project start with default template without using entities and message sources etc. I wish create application with full java configuration of message sources and `SpringSecurity`. As I understood in `application.properties` I write parameters for database connection only. But how I can set where `Spring` need find entities and other features?

Comment: In the same configuration file. I strongly suggest you take a read of the Spring Boot reference guide and especially what it can configure for you. That is a lot more then just a datasource.

Comment: And how I can set where the application need find `JSP` files and resources `css/`, `js/` etc...?

Comment: Again read the reference guide that is to much too explain in a comment. In short Spring Boot already exposes the `/resources/` directory (and more) for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Even If I exclude HibernateJpAAutoConfiguration, I got other error, please help me in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621001/configuration-jpa-with-spring-boot-is-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

The root of the problem lies in the [`DataSourceInitializedPublisher`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java) which publishes an event when certain beans have been registered. This bean is added by the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` class. This class tries to create a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` however in your configuration you are creating it yourself. Leading to early firing of events.

Excluding the `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` should fix the problem as that disable the registration of the `DataSourceInitializedPublisher`.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Regarding your configuration you can almost remove all of it and simply put some properties in the `application.properties` files.

Your `WebAppConfig`.

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        AbstractMessageSource messageSource = new Dictionary();
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

And in the `application.properties` add the following 2 properties

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Now your `RootConfig`.

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

And add the following properties to your `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform= // Hibernate Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

For more properties see the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Your `Initializer` can be removed as that doesn't do anything in a Spring Boot application. I might have missed a couple of properties but this should give you a start and feel for what Spring Boot can do for you.

Note: I'm not sure why you need both JPA and plain hibernate if you can do it with JPA only you can simply remove your `RootConfig` completely.

Comment: You are really strong man! Many thanks to you! In the morning I will try and report the results! Thank you!

Comment: @m-deinum , Hi! I still can't start my application. :) I need your help. Spring-boot application start but when I make request for http://localhost:8080/ , I retrieve this in console: http://pastebin.com/UYpYFkgn "pastebin" And in browser I have message:
Whitelabel Error Page
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: @MDeinum :) Can you look at my previous comment?

Comment: The error is quite clear... You don't have an `index.jsp` in your `/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory. Also you might want to take al ook at [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) of the reference guide regarding JSP with Spring Boot.

Comment: No. I have properties in application.properties:
`spring.resources=/resources/**
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
`
I have the same as in example, Application main class:
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "lv.intrade.example")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
 return application.sources(Application.class);
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}`

Comment: And I have the structure /project_root/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/

main/java/lv.intrade.exaple/***

main/resources/application.properties

Comment: I found one problem. I put the webapp folder as my resource folder and then I can get my JSP page but in full text mode. JSP sources was not compiled.