# Configuration JPA with spring boot is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

At first, I got this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@78bd863d: startup date [Thu Sep 17 14:11:50 KST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapab
```

And I found the workaround in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712968/springboot-application-crash) and added the exclude property that caused the error above.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource( {"classpath:/config/*.xml"  } )
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class Starter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Starter.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);
    }
```

But I got other error again.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:575)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

This error have started after i add the messgesource bean.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.xxx.redca.hub.common.context.support.DatabaseDrivenMessageSource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.module.messagemgn.service.MessageService" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.language.service.LanguageMgnService" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="#{comProps['defaultLang']}" />
</bean>



public class DatabaseDrivenMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource  implements ResourceLoaderAware{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    private final Map<String, Map<String, String>> properties = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    private String defaultLang;

    private MessageService messageService;

    private LanguageMgnService languageMgnService;
```

---

**UPDATE2**

I am using two kinds of orm both jpa and mybatis.

Orm is set by spring-data-jpa and mybatis is set by spring xml.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://70.121.224.51:3306/faro
spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/init.dml/TB_FR_LANGUAGE_INFO_INITDATA.sql,classpath:/init.dml/TB_FR_MESSAGE_INFO_INITDATA.sql

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**XML Configuration**

There are so many files. But I attached files that seemed to be related.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">


    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:/properties/mysql.datasource.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://70.121.224.51:3306/faro" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="logStatementsEnabled" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageSource" class="com.xxx.redca.hub.common.context.support.DatabaseDrivenMessageSource">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.module.messagemgn.service.MessageService" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.language.service.LanguageMgnService" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="#{comProps['defaultLang']}" />
    </bean>
```

**Update3**

My pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.2.201409121644</jacoco.version>
        <jacoco.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.reportPath>
        <system.score.path>${project.basedir}/lib</system.score.path>
        <querydsl.version>4.0.1</querydsl.version>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <java.home>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51</java.home>
        <!-- <java.home>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40</java.home> -->
        <!-- <datasource.type>h2</datasource.type> -->
    </properties>

<dependencies>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.7.7</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- for aui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.anyframe</groupId>
            <artifactId>anyframe-ui-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>lego.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>lego-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/lego-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.anyframe</groupId>
            <artifactId>anyframe-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- mysinge api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-mysingle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/axis-mysingle-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery-mysingle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/commons-discovery-mysingle-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ESBMailService</groupId>
            <artifactId>ESBMailService</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/ESBMailService.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ESBService_EMP_ORG_MAIL</groupId>
            <artifactId>ESBService_EMP_ORG_MAIL.jar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/ESBService_EMP_ORG_MAIL.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-mysingle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/jaxrpc-mysingle-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/mail-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-mysingle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/saaj-mysingle-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j-mysingle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/wsdl4j-mysingle-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncycastle-jce-jdk13</artifactId>
            <version>112</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aui-fileuploader</groupId>
            <artifactId>aui-fileuploader</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- mybatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.726</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
            <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**UPDATE 4**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.language.dao.LanguageMgnDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6f2735cc: startup date [Thu Sep 17 17:53:23 KST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6f2735cc: startup date [Thu Sep 17 17:53:23 KST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:565)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6f2735cc: startup date [Thu Sep 17 17:53:23 KST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1719)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
    ... 63 more
```

The class

```
@Repository("com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.language.dao.LanguageMgnDao")
public class LanguageMgnDaoImpl implements LanguageMgnDao{

    @Autowired
    private LegoSqlTemplate sqlTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SequenceIdGenerator generator;

    private final static  String sqlStatement="LanguageMgn.";

    // jpa repo
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    //@Autowired
    //EntityManagerFactory emf;

    JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {

        //System.out.println("=============================>>>>LanguageMgnDaoImpl "+em);
        //System.out.println("=============================>>>>LanguageMgnDaoImpl "+emf);

        //em = emf.createEntityManager();

        queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping your `MessageSource` in a lazy proxy, which delays the creation of the bean until it is actually used.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">        
    <property name="targetSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.target.LazyInitTargetSource">
            <property name="targetClass" value="com.xxx.redca.hub.common.context.support.DatabaseDrivenMessageSource" />            
            <property name="targetBeanName" value="lazyMessageSource"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="lazyMessageSource" class="com.xxx.redca.hub.common.context.support.DatabaseDrivenMessageSource" lazy-init="true">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.module.messagemgn.service.MessageService" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="com.xxx.redca.hub.admin.language.service.LanguageMgnService" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="#{comProps['defaultLang']}" />
</bean>
```

Now at startup you get the proxy and as soon it is used to retrieve messages it will be actually instantiated and used. This should delay it enough.

Comment: But is it still workaround when if  it use bean in constructor method?

Comment: I passed 3 parameters for the constructor method and it is executed.  I tried this but got null pointer exception.

Comment: I changed the bean to be load by the bean factory and adapted the proxy bean for it. but when it created (because the logic called in the constructor method), it gets null object when it get object from getbean() method.

Comment: I still don't get what you are saying... What logic... You shouldn't have logic in your constructor as that would interfere with prober bean instantiation... If you want to execute something do it in a a `@PostConstruct` annotated method NOT the constructor....